# Problema en traspaso de datos en ajax(php y jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo mi archivo de modelo-prestamo.php (donde hago la consulta a la base de datos la cual se ejecuta a la perfecion) y el archivo de jQuery. Por alguna razon la informacion que quiero pasar del archivo PHP al jQuery me aparece en la pagina php y eso obviamente no deberia pasar. Deberia leer los datos pasados y ejecutar la funcion pero no ir al modelo. Les agradeceria su ayuda, saludos.
HTML:

form role="form" name="guardar-registro" id="guardar-registro" method="post" action="modelo-prestamo.php"
              
                
                  Banco:
                  
                
                
                  N° Operacion:

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha_acuerdo">Fecha de Acuerdo:</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_acuerdo"  name="fecha_acuerdo" placeholder="fecha_acuerdo">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha_vto">Fecha de Vencimiento:</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_vto"  name="fecha_vto" placeholder="fecha_vto">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cant_ctas">Cantidad de cuotas:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cant_ctas"  name="cant_ctas" placeholder="cant_ctas">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="coutas_pagas">Cuotas pagas:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coutas_pagas"  name="coutas_pagas" placeholder="coutas_pagas">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="capital">Capital:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capital"  name="capital" placeholder="capital">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="intereses">Intereses:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intereses"  name="intereses" placeholder="intereses">
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar-registro">Añadir</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

PHP(modelo-prestamo.php):
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo'){

```
if(!filter_var($banco, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){
    die('Ingresa una cadena de letras de titulo, por favor');
}

if(!filter_var($noperacion, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en numero de operacion, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($fecha_acuerdo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){
    die('Ingresa una fecha de acuerdo, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($fecha_vto, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){
    die('Ingresa una fecha de vencimiento, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($cant_ctas, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en cantidad de cuotas, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($coutas_pagas, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en cantidad de cuotas pagas, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($iva, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en IVA , por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($capital, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en capital, por favor');
}
if(!filter_var($intereses, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
    die('Ingresa un numero en intereses, por favor');
}

try{

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamos (nombre_prestamo, noperacion, fecha_acuerdo, fecha_vto, cantidad_ctas, ctas_pagas, iva, capital, intereses, pagar ,total, restantes, total_mes) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
 $stmt->bind_param('sissiiiiiiiii', $banco, $noperacion, $fecha_acuerdo, $fecha_vto, $cant_ctas, $coutas_pagas, $iva, $capital, $intereses, $pagar ,$total, $restantes, $total_por_mes);
 $stmt->execute();
 $id_registro =  $stmt->insert_id;
 if ($id_registro > 0) {
    $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_prestamo' => $id_registro
    );

 }else{
    $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error',
    );
 }
 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();

}catch(Exception $e){
    print 'error: '. $e->getMessage();
}
    die(json_encode($respuesta));
```

}

JS:
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#guardar-registro').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: datos,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            var resultado = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(resultado);

                    if (resultado.respuesta === 'exito') {
                        Swal(
                              'Correcto!',
                              'Se guardo correctamente',
                              'success'
                            )
                    }else{
                        Swal(
                              'Error!',
                              'Hubo un error!',
                              'error'
                            )
                    }
        }

    })
});
```

})

Espera que puedan ayudarme porque me estoy volviendo loco jaja, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

al parecer te falta devolver el arreglo empleando la función de ECHO, por lo que al final tendrías que dejarlo así:
          try{

```
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamos (nombre_prestamo, noperacion, 
                        fecha_acuerdo, fecha_vto, cantidad_ctas, ctas_pagas, iva, 
                        capital, intereses, pagar ,total, restantes, total_mes) 
                       VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
          $stmt->bind_param('sissiiiiiiiii', $banco, $noperacion, $fecha_acuerdo, 
                            $fecha_vto, $cant_ctas, $coutas_pagas, $iva, $capital, 
                            $intereses, $pagar ,$total, $restantes, $total_por_mes);
          $stmt->execute();
          $id_registro =  $stmt->insert_id;
         if ($id_registro > 0) {
            $respuesta = array('respuesta' => 'exito',
                               'id_prestamo' => $id_registro);

          }else{
            $respuesta = array('respuesta' => 'error',);
          }
          $stmt->close();
          $conn->close();

    }catch(Exception $e){
         print 'error: '. $e->getMessage();
    }

      echo json_encode($respuesta);  //retorna los datos al ajax
```

Espero pueda servirte esta respuesta, ya que así es como actualmente devuelvo datos desde php al ajax.